# typescript project references and JavaScript files

Tags: typescript, tsc, tsconfig

I have a mixed ts and js project that works fine with the `allowJS: true` setting in `tsconfig`.

I now want to use [Project references](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html) which need `composite: true` which means the `allowJS` can't be used.

Does this mean I can only use Project references in a purely typescript project?

When I run `tsc -b` because the js files are not included the output code is missing declarations!

How can I still include the js code in my project but use the newer Project references?

Answer (score 2):

TS 3.7 allows `declaration` and `allowJs` [to be used together](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#--declaration-and---allowjs) ([PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/32372)). You should be able to use project references (requires `declaration`) together with compiled JavaScript source files now.